# Bluetooth crashing when streaming on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, bluetooth

I've got a problem with my bluetooth drivers on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.
When I first load the OS, I can see the bluetooth tray icon, and even connect to my bluetooth headset. The moment I try to stream something to the headset, the bluetooth crashes, and I can't reactivate it in any way other than restarting my computer.

Some logs:

```
 # dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    4.223998] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    4.224011] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.224013] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.224015] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.224021] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.317038] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011002270d39
[    4.317039] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 39
[    4.393310] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.393311] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.393313] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    7.552520] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    7.552528] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    7.552532] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  238.609823] Bluetooth: hci0 setting interface failed (19)
[  241.041785] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[  241.041786] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[  241.068201] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011002270d39
[  241.068202] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 39
```

---

```
 # lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; lsmod | grep blue
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM [8086:15a2] (rev 03)
DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM [1028:062e]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 3b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5510]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5804 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor with fingerprint swipe sensor
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2b8d Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c01e Logitech, Inc. MX518 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:07a5 Microsoft Corp. Wireless Receiver 1461C
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
bluetooth             557056  15 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
 # rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

This has already happened with 2 different headsets, so I doubt it has anything to do with these headsets.

After the bluetooth crashes, this is what the bluetooth manager looks like:

[image: bluetooth manager]

As you can see, even though I activated the bluetooth, it is disabled. And even though the "Show bluetooth status in the menu bar" is checked, I see nothing.

I tried to reinstall bluez, with no change.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use **Blueman applet 1.23** from Ubuntu software center. Which will solve your Bluetooth crashing problem

Comment: I did that, and when I try to connect to my headsets I'm getting `Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Host is down`

Comment: Follow the steps 1. `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` 2. pactl load-module module-Bluetooth-discover 3.Delete the device from bluetooth devices and pair it again.  This will be help full to you (https://zach-adams.com/2014/07/bluetooth-audio-sink-stream-setup-failed/)

Comment: When I do step 2, I get an error `Failure: Module initialization failed`